# why this message appear when run flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, sdk

when I run android flutter  appears This problem

Exception: [!] Your app is using an unsupported Gradle project. To fix this problem, create a new project by running `flutter create -t app <app-directory>` and then move the dart code, assets and pubspec.yaml to the new project.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused because you are using `older version` / `customized version` or if the `gradle version is broken` for some reason and it may not be compatible with the project.

To fix this problem, you can follow the instructions as in the error message and create a new `Flutter` project using the flutter `create` command. and then you can move your  Dart code, assets, and `pubspec.yaml` file to the new project.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a serious issue at all. You might have accidentally **deleted a line** from the `[android/app/build.gradle] file, which is: [apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"]`. Try typing it again if it's not there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!